# ElasticSearch Java Scan and scroll return empty list

Tags: elasticsearch

all:
  Now, I want to delete data in es by date using 'es scan and scroll'. At first, it work well. Some day, it doesn't work. The response is return with empty result list.
  Then, I have tried to delete the code - 'set SearchType=Scan', and it works. However, the scroll operation became particularly slow. And now, I run the code on another ES Cluster, and it works well.

ES version: 2.1.2
  Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = args[0];
    logger.info("delete date:" + date);
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.termQuery("date", date);

    Client client = EsConfigUtil.getClient();
    new DeleteDataByDate().scanEs(client, qb, 6000, "ad_user_info", "impression_user_data");
}

private void scanEs(Client client, QueryBuilder qb, int size, String indices, String indexType) {
    SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(indices)
            .**setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)**  // THIE IS THE KEY.
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
            .setQuery(qb)
            .setSize(size).execute().actionGet();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Scroll until no hits are returned
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = null;
    long totalNum = 0;
    while (true) {
        long scanStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (scrollResp.getHits().hits().length > 0) {
            bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
            for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
                bulkRequest.add(client.prepareDelete(indices, indexType, hit.getId()));
                totalNum += 1;
            }
            BulkResponse response = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
            logger.info("bulk time:" + response.getTookInMillis());
        }
        scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .execute().actionGet();
        if (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
            logger.error("hits length is 0, QB:" + qb.toString());
            break;
        }
        logger.info("scan time :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - scanStart));
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("total time:" + (end - start));
    logger.info("total handle num:" + totalNum);
}
```

MY POOR ENGLISH, HELP ME!!!

Comment: Why don't you simply use the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.1/plugins-delete-by-query.html) which does exactly what you need?

Comment: I used the plugin ever,but  it is very slow. I think the reason is that I didn't change any config. I will try it again.

Comment: hi, i found it that th delete-by-query plugin is very slow, how can i make it faster?